# Setting up Google Cloud Messenging (GCM) with Amazon Web Services (AWS) Simple Notification Service (SNS)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, google-api, amazon-sns

I want to create an app on my sns and whenever I enter my app API details I get the following error

`The credentials you entered are invalid. Please enter valid credentials and try again.`

I have done the following:

Google Console -> Selected Project -> Selected APIs & Auth -> Selected Credentials -> Create new Key -> Browser key

Then entered the site in the information `*mysite.systems/*`

I then go to the Google Play Developer Console and do the following:
Select Application-> Select Services & APIs -> Link a sender ID -> Enter API key from above. This is accepted

I then for to my AWS console and in SNS do the following

```
Application Name: RandomName
Push Platform: Google Cloud Messenging (GCM)
API key: API key from before
```

This does not work and produces the above error.

I tried the same process except chose the public API key as a server key instead. The value I entered was `0.0.0.0/0.` as [Google suggests as a test](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html). This then worked fine. The problem is I can not use an IP address as I am using a Load balancer for my AWS account which does not have an IP so this is not possible.

Also I have also followed this question and it did not work for me: [Cannot create AWS-SNS GCM account, showing invalid credentials message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826372/cannot-create-aws-sns-gcm-account-showing-invalid-credentials-message)

Thanks

*EDIT
A month later and I am still looking for a solution...

*EDIT 2
A answer to this question has still not been provided and I have still not solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

It was worked for me when I go for server key, but instead of `0.0.0.0` I left the textbox for `IP` is empty.
Good luck!