# Amazon SNS push notification integration in android "Platform Credential Invalid"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to integrate `Amazon SNS Push Notification service` in my android app.

What I have done:

1. Created new app.
2. Integrated with `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to get "API Key".
3. Now, on AWS console I'm creating a new platform application and providing the same "API Key" what I received from Google FCM.

However, after doing all the above steps I am able to see the below error message on AWS console:

> Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 9c385a89-20c3-54e7-b0f0-0a57ffa6a30b)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429554/5832311). I've seen in the comment the the OP tried to created a new key (in Firebase) and had to update the app accordingly.

Also, based from this [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=510184), when you register an app in google cloud console `(Projects > APIs & auth > Registered apps > Register app)`, you have to select `Accessing APIs via a web server` option inside "Android" option in Platform. Once you create it, select API Key in server key section. That key is correct and lets you create the app in AWS console.

You may also to contact the [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting) if the error still persists.